# Display loading message while Exporting a results set to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, loading

I'm using ASP.NET and C# and am exporting a very large results set to Excel.  While my export code is running I would like to show a "loading" animated gif so the users will know their request is processing.  I've been trying to do this with multithreading, but I am not very familiar with it.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Jon

Comment: How long does it take?  longer than 30 seconds?

Comment: It was taking around 30 seconds, but realized it was a problem with the SP generating the report.  Now it's down to just a few seconds.  I'd still like to figure this out though for future reference (and to learn more).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do multi-threading on the server? What I'd recommend is in your client side javascript turn on a please wait message before posting to the server. Then on the client side when your done posting you turn the message off.

Without knowing more about your actual setup I can't help much further, but last time I implemented this I did something along these lines:

Assume we have a div called PrintLoadingPanel using JQUERY I set the div to display and take over the window:

```
    $("#printLoadingPanel")
       .css({display:"block",top:"0px",left:"0px",height:screen.availHeight});
```

I then will start a timer with a 1/2 second interval which will start checking if we are done printing. I'm only generating and downloading small PDF's so i needed a quicker response. If your report is really slow you might want to tweak this:

```
    window.setTimeout(checkIfDoneDownload,500);
```

Then my CheckIfDoneDownload function hits the server and checks if we finished generating the file and downloaded it. I am using JQUERY here again to call an AJAX enabled WCF service. You could substitute this with PageMethods or any other way to callback to the server.

```
function checkIfDoneDownload()
{

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../Services/Utilities.svc/IsPrintDownloadDone",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
  if (msg.d)
  {
    $("#printLoadingPanel").css("display","none");
  }
  else  {window.setTimeout(checkIfDoneDownload,500);}
  },  
  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  if (xhr.status==12030) {checkIfDoneDownload();}
}
});
}
```

Now on the server side, I am generating my downloads via an HTTP Handler. Essentially the first thing it does is set a session level flag to false, then the last thing it does is set it back to true. My check if done service just returns the value of the flag.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use multi-threading on the server.  I'll give your solution a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same problem with generating reports.  A simple solution would be to run the report at night and then write it to the server.  Then provide a link to the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a position to use ASP.NET AJAX then I'd recommend using the [`UpdateProgress`](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/Tutorials/IntroductionUpdateProgress.aspx) control (along with an `UpdatePanel`).

If you're after a nice animated gif image then check out [Ajaxload](http://ajaxload.info/).

Comment: I tried this but the export to Excel failed because it requires a Response.Write()